# Scale out with K8S

Tags: kubernetes

We have a pod which uses Java based HTTP server. HTTP POST requests are sent to the server from JMeter. We are currently measuring scale-out percentage for this http server by increasing the number of replicas. Attached here is deployment yaml which is configured to use both nodePort and hostPort for exposing the service.

Our tests shows nodePort scale-out percentage is 57 whereas hostPort scale-out  percentage is ~95.

We would like to know why this difference in behavior and how to tune nodePort to get scale-out percentage same as hostPort.

Given below are test details:

> **K8S version:** v1.9.6,
>
> **system details:** 1 master, 3 worker, 1 NFS server
>
> **OS:** CentOS Linux release 7.3
>
> **System resource:** 16 GiB RAM(in each K8S node), 12 CPU (in each K8S
>   node), 1 TB storage.

[Deployment YAML file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17CdnbGImp99sK6SduomO9xMg2vXby8zn/view?usp=sharing):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: itom-di-receiver-svc
  namespace: opsbridge1
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - name: receiver-port
    nodePort: 30001
    port: 8443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 5050
  selector:
    app: itom-di-receiver

---

apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: itom-di-receiver-dpl
  namespace: opsbridge1
  annotations:
    deployment.microfocus.com/default-replica-count: "1"
    deployment.microfocus.com/runlevel: UP
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: itom-di-receiver
      annotations:
        pod.boostport.com/vault-approle: opsbridge1-di
        pod.boostport.com/vault-init-container: install
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: itom-di-receiver-cnt
          image: localhost:5000/hpeswitomsandbox/itom-data-ingestion-receiver:1.3.0-029
          livenessProbe:
            exec:
              command:
              - cat
              - /receiver/receiver-status.txt
            initialDelaySeconds: 180
            periodSeconds: 20
          readinessProbe:
            exec:
              command:
              - "/receiver/bin/readiness.sh"
            initialDelaySeconds: 30
            periodSeconds: 20
            failureThreshold: 18
          securityContext:
            capabilities:
              drop:
                - all
              add:
                - CHOWN
                - SETGID
                - SETUID
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          env:
          - name: gid
            value: "1999"
          - name: uid
            value: "1999"
          - name: KAFKA_SECURITY_PROTOCOL
            value: "SSL"
          - name: KAFKA_HOSTNAME
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                name: itom-di-kafka-cm
                key: kafka.advertised.host.name
          - name: KAFKA_PORT
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                name: itom-di-kafka-cm
                key: kafka.advertised.port
          - name: KAFKA_DEFAULT_TOPIC
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                name: itom-di-receiver-cm
                key: kafka.default.topic
          - name: KAFKA_MAP_CONTEXT_TO_TOPIC
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                name: itom-di-receiver-cm
                key: kafka.map.context.to.topic
          - name: RECEIVER_KAFKA_TLS_ENABLE
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                name: itom-di-receiver-cm
                key: receiver.kafka.tls.enable
          - name: RECEIVER_JVM_ARGS
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                name: itom-di-receiver-cm
                key: receiver.jvm.args
           ### Receiver Performance Tuning Environment Variables ###
          - name: RECEIVER_COMPUTE_THREADS
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                name: itom-di-receiver-cm
                key: receiver.compute.threads
          - name: KAFKA_PRODUCER_BATCH_SIZE
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                name: itom-di-receiver-cm
                key: receiver.kafka.producer.batch.size.kb
          - name: RECEIVER_REQUEST_BODY_MAXSIZE_MB
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                name: itom-di-receiver-cm
                key: receiver.request.body.maxsize.mb
          - name: KAFKA_PRODUCER_LINGER_MS
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                name: itom-di-receiver-cm
                key: receiver.kafka.producer.linger.ms
          - name: KAFKA_PRODUCER_ACKS
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                name: itom-di-receiver-cm
                key: receiver.kafka.producer.acks
          - name: KAFKA_PRODUCER_COMPRESSION_TYPE
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                name: itom-di-receiver-cm
                key: receiver.kafka.producer.compression.type
          - name: KAFKA_PRODUCER_BUFFER_MEMORY
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                name: itom-di-receiver-cm
                key: receiver.kafka.producer.buffer.memory.mb
          - name: KAFKA_PRODUCER_MAX_BLOCK_MS
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                name: itom-di-receiver-cm
                key: receiver.kafka.producer.max.block.ms
          - name: RECEIVER_HEADER_FIELDNAME_FOR_TOPIC
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                name: itom-di-receiver-cm
                key: receiver.header.fieldname.for.topic
          - name: RECEIVER_HEADER_FIELDNAME_FOR_TOPIC_KEY
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                name: itom-di-receiver-cm
                key: receiver.header.fieldname.for.topic.key
          - name: RECEIVER_TOPIC_FROM_HEADER
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                name: itom-di-receiver-cm
                key: receiver.topic.from.header
          - name: KAFKA_PRODUCER_RETRIES
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                name: itom-di-receiver-cm
                key: receiver.kafka.producer.retries
          - name: KAFKA_PRODUCER_MAX_IN_FLIGHT_REQUEST_PER_CONNECTION
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                name: itom-di-receiver-cm
                key: receiver.kafka.producer.max.in.flight.requests.per.connection

          ### Security Environment Variables ###
          - name: RECEIVER_PROTOCOL
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                name: itom-di-receiver-cm
                key: receiver.protocol
          - name: RECEIVER_AUTH_METHOD
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                name: itom-di-receiver-cm
                key: receiver.auth.method
          - name: RECEIVER_KEYSTORE_TYPE
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                name: itom-di-receiver-cm
                key: receiver.keystore.type
          - name: RECEIVER_TRUSTSTORE_TYPE
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                name: itom-di-receiver-cm
                key: receiver.truststore.type
          - name: RECEIVER_EXTERNAL_JAR_ENABLE
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                name: itom-di-receiver-cm
                key: receiver.external.jar.enable
          - name: RECEIVER_JAR_VALIDATE
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                name: itom-di-receiver-cm
                key: receiver.jar.validate
          - name: CERTIFICATE_REVOCATION
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                name: itom-di-receiver-cm
                key: receiver.cert.revocation.enable
          - name: CRL_FILE
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                name: itom-di-receiver-cm
                key: receiver.cert.revocation.crlfile.enable
          - name: PREFER_OCSP
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                name: itom-di-receiver-cm
                key: receiver.cert.revocation.ocsp.enable
          - name: ENABLE_SOFT_FAIL
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                name: itom-di-receiver-cm
                key: receiver.cert.revocation.softfail.enable
          - name: PREFER_CRL
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                name: itom-di-receiver-cm
                key: receiver.cert.revocation.preferCRL.enable
          - name: RESPONDER_URL
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                name: itom-di-receiver-cm
                key: ocsp.responderURL
          - name: CERT_SUBJECT_NAME
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                name: itom-di-receiver-cm
                key: ocsp.responderCertSubjectName
          - name: CERT_ISSUER_NAME
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                name: itom-di-receiver-cm
                key: ocsp.responderCertIssuerName
          - name: CERT_SERIAL_NUMBER
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                name: itom-di-receiver-cm
                key: ocsp.responderCertSerialNumber
          - name: RECEIVER_FIPS_ENABLE
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                name: itom-di-receiver-cm
                key: receiver.fips.enable
          - name: RECEIVER_APIKEY_REFRESH_INTERVAL_MINS
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                name: itom-di-receiver-cm
                key: receiver.apikey.refresh.interval.mins
          ports:
          - containerPort: 5050
            hostPort: 5051
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: "4"
              memory: "2048Mi"
            requests:
              cpu: "1"
              memory: "1024Mi"
          volumeMounts:
          - name: di-receiver-volume
            mountPath: /receiver/conf
            subPath: di/receiver/conf
          - name: di-receiver-volume
            mountPath: /receiver/conf/endpoint
            subPath: di/receiver/conf/endpoint
          - name: di-receiver-volume
            mountPath: /receiver/conf/schema
            subPath: di/receiver/conf/schema
          - name: di-receiver-volume
            mountPath: /receiver/conf/crl
            subPath: di/receiver/conf/crl
          - name: di-receiver-log-volume
            mountPath: /receiver/log
            subPath: di/receiver/log
          - name: di-receiver-volume
            mountPath: /receiver/ext
            subPath: di/receiver/ext
          - name: di-receiver-volume
            mountPath: /receiver/data
            subPath: di/receiver/data
          - name: di-receiver-volume
            mountPath: /receiver/samples
            subPath: di/receiver/samples
          - name: vault-token
            mountPath: /var/run/secrets/boostport.com
          - name: secret-volume
            mountPath: /receiver/ssl/ca
          - name: secret-volume-kafka
            mountPath: /receiver/ssl/store/receiver-kafka
        - name: kubernetes-vault-renew
          image: localhost:5000/kubernetes-vault-renew:0.5.0
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          volumeMounts:
          - name: vault-token
            mountPath: /var/run/secrets/boostport.com
      initContainers:
      - env:
        - name: VAULT_ROLE_ID
          value: "66d8c1aa-6079-a65f-38c3-89bd7a6fdd2c"
        - name: CERT_COMMON_NAME
          value: "smperfqa31.hpeswlab.net"
        image: localhost:5000/kubernetes-vault-init:0.5.0
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: install
        resources: {}
        securityContext:
          runAsUser: 1999
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/boostport.com
            name: vault-token
      - name: itom-di-init-receiver-cnt
        image: localhost:5000/hpeswitomsandbox/itom-data-ingestion-receiver:1.3.0-029
        command: ["/receiver/bin/run.sh","dependency"]
        env:
        - name: KAFKA_HOSTNAME
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: itom-di-kafka-cm
              key: kafka.advertised.host.name
      volumes:
        - name: di-receiver-volume
          persistentVolumeClaim:
             claimName: conf-volume
        - name: di-receiver-log-volume
          persistentVolumeClaim:
             claimName: log-volume
        - name: vault-token
          emptyDir: {}
        - name: secret-volume
          secret:
            secretName: receiver-secret
        - name: secret-volume-kafka
          secret:
            secretName: receiver-kafka-secret
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly with scale out percentage and how do you measure it? With node port the traffic should be balanced by K8s between the pods and it should be possible to run multiple pods on the same node. With host port there can be only one pod per host (due to port collisions) which is normally a bad thing.

Comment: We are measuring scale out percentage by calculating percentage increase in throughput in Jmeter when we increase the replica from 1 to 2 http server pod deployment. 
Yes, host port scenario does not allow to run more than one pod on the same worker node. So node port is the preferred deployment for us.

Comment: In the test scenario, the http server pods run on different worker nodes in both node port and host port scenario. In node port scenario, two JMeter instances were configured to send requests to one worker node. We also tested with message flowing from  JMeter->HAProxy->worker nodes(round robin/least connection). In host port scenario,two Jmeter instances were configured with one sending to worker node 1 and another sending to worker node 2.

Comment: I think you should repeat the tests with matching configurations. If you use HAProxy with round robin and a single JMeter for one case you should do the same for the other. Or use two JMeter instances for both tests. With the current setup the bottleneck may well be on the client side.

Comment: In host port scenario we used two JMeter clients, one sending to worker node 1 and the other sending to worker node 2. Similarly, even in node port scenario
we used two JMeter clients one sending to worker node 1 and another sending to worker node 2.

Comment: In addition we also tested two more additional scenarios: one using HA Proxy as mentioned in earlier message, and another scenario in which both JMeter clients sent messages to same worker node. So totally 3 scenarios were tested for node port scenario as we wanted to see if the performance in any of these scenarios match with the performance we see for host port.

Comment: We expected an overhead in node port scenario but we didn’t expect the difference to be so high. Is there any configuration or tuning that can be done to improve the performance in node port scenario?